# Getting TypeError: _react.default.memo is not a function only when I use FavoriteIcon in my app

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

My app was running fine without any issue. But it started throwing error as below when I started using material ui component named FavoriteIcon.

```
import FavoriteIcon from "@material-ui/icons/FavoriteBorderOutlined";
```

Getting below error

```
TypeError: _react.default.memo is not a function
createSvgIcon

  14 | var _SvgIcon = _interopRequireDefault(require("@material-ui/core/SvgIcon"));
  15 | 
  16 | function createSvgIcon(path, displayName) {
> 17 |   var Component = _react.default.memo(_react.default.forwardRef(function (props, ref) {
  18 |     return _react.default.createElement(_SvgIcon.default, (0, _extends2.default)({}, props, {
  19 |       ref: ref
  20 |     }), path);
```

Comment: what version of React are you using in your project?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when I was upgrading the dependencies of my project.

Try to use the last version of react, redux and react-redux.

My package.json:

```
{
    "@material-ui/core": "^3.9.3",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.2.1",
    "react": "^16.8.6",
    "react-dom": "^16.8.6",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
}
```

You can verify if you use the correct versions with:

```
npm outdated
```

Hope it will solve your problem, it worked for me ! :)